Customization of page numbering
I am aware that I can change the number manually using the \setcounter{page}{n} command for the page number n. What I am looking for is a way to change the font of the counter.
This is specifically meant for the footer in an document with Doc. Class Article

You have to edit the page style. For example, you can use fancyhdr package for this.

Do please tell us which document class is in use.

Welcome! Do you mean in the header/footer or cross-references or where? Can you provide code for a minimal example?

There isn't really a font of a counter. And IMHO this also would not make much sense, because the page counter is used at several places, e.g., at the page header or footer, the table of contents or by \pageref{…}. Because of using the tag header-footer I guess, that you want to change the color of the page number in the page header or footer.
With package scrlayer-scrpage changing of the color of the page number in the (predefined) page header or page footer is similar to a change of the font very easy using \setkomafont or \addtokomafont:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\color{Magenta}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{blindtext}% Just for the dummy text of the example.

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}


Note, that you cannot mix package scrlayer-scrpage with other page-header/footer-packages like fancyhdr. So if you already use another package for page headers and footers, you have to use the user interface of that package instead.
Instead of page scrlayer-scrpage you can alternatively use, e.g., package fancyhdr. In this case, is could make sense to change not only the fancy page style, but also the plain page style explicitly:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[C]{\rmfamily\color{Magenta}\thepage}% page number in the page footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all header and footer fields
  \fancyfoot[C]{\rmfamily\color{Magenta}\thepage}% page number in the page footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% no header separation rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% no footer separation rule
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{blindtext}% Just for the dummy text of the example.

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}

The result would be the same as shown above.
Note, that you cannot mix package fancyhdr with other page-header/footer-packages like scrlayer-scrpage. So if you already use another package for page headers and footers, you have to use the user interface of that package instead.
However, if you really want something, like the color of the page counter everywhere, you can redefine \thepage:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\colorlet{pagenumber}{Magenta}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\textcolor{pagenumber}{\arabic{page}}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% Just for the dummy text of the example.

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First}\label{sec:first}

This first sections starts on page~\pageref{sec:first}. And the first appendix
section starts on page~\pageref{apx:first}.

\blinddocument

\appendix
\colorlet{pagenumber}{DarkGreen}% show page numbers in the appendix in DarkGreen
\section{First Appendix}\label{apx:first}
This first appendix section starts on page~\pageref{apx:first}. And the first
main section starts on page~\pageref{sec:first}.

\blindtext

\end{document}

or
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\textcolor{Magenta}{\arabic{page}}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% Just for the dummy text of the example.

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First}\label{sec:first}

This first sections starts on page~\pageref{sec:first}. And the first appendix
section starts on page~\pageref{apx:first}.

\blinddocument

\appendix
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\textcolor{DarkGreen}{\arabic{page}}}% show page numbers of the appendix in DarkGreen
\section{First Appendix}\label{apx:first}
This first appendix section starts on page~\pageref{apx:first}. And the first
main section starts on page~\pageref{sec:first}.

\blindtext

\end{document}

Note, that the results of these two examples are different!
